# Is there a way to git add the second file from unstaged files to the staging area?

Tags: git

`git status` gives:

```
On branch sid-x
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   longpath/x.java
    modified:   longpath/x.html
    modified:   longpath/x.py
```

I would like to add x.html to my staging area. Is there a flag or a way to do this apart from writing out `git add longpath/x.py`?

Comment: What is the reason to avoid `git add`?

Comment: you trying to avoid `git add` or `longpath`?

Comment: if you want to add `x.html` to staging area; do you mean you don't want to write `git add longpath/x.html`?

Comment: Most modern terminals have a copy/paste feature. Many even do this with one click of the mouse. This can be used for other task as well.

Comment: well I just wanted to have a quick way to add a particular file instead of having to copy the longpath. @JosephK.Strauss Can you tell me how I can do a copy+paste with a single click?

Comment: @It depends on the terminal, but Git Bash for Windows, which is what I use allows it from Options -> Mouse -> Right click action -> Paste. When I SSH to a remote machine with Putty this is the default. In these terminals, selecting copies and right-click pastes, so if you highlight and right-click, voila, it gets copy pasted. (I guess you may call that two clicks because you need to select first, but I was not counting the selection part.) In the above-mentioned terminals double-clicking selects the entire word so it is even easy to select a long word.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `git add --interactive`. This will bring you to a UI that will let you select what you want to do without having to type out the whole path to the file you want to add (if thats what your concern was). Or use a GUI that lets you select files you want to add by clicking, so you dont have to type out the path. Or just do a `find` on it and xarg pass that to git add.

Comment: Didn't know about interactive mode. Thanks.